# Optimization problem: Finding the maximum value

Tags: optimization

Can someone please give me a hint on this problem? I want to find the maximum value of y, given the equations:

[image]

Comment: Try the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $G^*G$.

Comment: I am a little bit confused... Maximum eigenvalue of G or $G^TG$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the $2$-norm, the quantity you are trying to maximize is the induced norm of the matrix $G$ (assuming as well that $G$ is meant to be a matrix and $u$ a vector of compatible dimension). Since you are maximizing the square of the induced norm of $G$, this will give you the square of the largest singular value of $G$. If $G$ has full rank, it will give you 
\begin{equation}
\max_{\lambda \,\,\in \,\,eigval(G)} |\lambda|
\end{equation}
namely, the numerical value here is the maximum of the absolute value of any eigenvalue of $G$.

Comment: I see. So I think the minimum value of y is zero, in case *u* is an eigenvector of $G^TG$. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try Cauchy-Schwarz inequality